# Allocating memory in C# is not actually allocating memory

Tags: c#, arrays, memory, garbage-collection, ram

When I declare a new byte array, the memory usage does not increase.

```
byte[] test = new[1024*100];
```

Its only after I iterate through each byte does it actually start taking ram.

How can I make it actually commit the memory without having to use it first?

I am using this as a test with a try catch block to see if it will fail to allocate the memory, thus telling me that my application is out of ram and it should not attempt to allocate any new objects.

Edit: since the objects I am going to be allocating are used with the garbage collector and stack, I don't want to allocate using malloc since it might succeed there, but fail when trying to allocate a new managed object.

Comment: Use special viewers such as Process Exporer and you will see this does allocate memory. It doesn't show in commited but once you iterate check the commited go up. You cannot allocate more than 2 gb to 1 object IIRC

Comment: @John could you try to change the value of the last element to ensure the array memory is allocated??

Comment: @Franck yes, I want to have it actually use the ram, appear in the task manager, and fail to allocate when I attempt it allocate it. Right now, it feels like it dynamically allocates blocks upon usage.

Comment: @John Yes that how it's design. Some application with high memory usage it is good to allocate memory at start i.e allocate 6 gb. This prevent other application from allocating all this ram. Then you are certain that you have at least that much to work with. This is pretty much the same principle that is happening here. You are telling you program to secure X amount of byte for that variable but it's not "used" yet, it might be and it might not but you have to space for it if need be.

Comment: @John What is the problem that you are _actually_ trying to solve? (Your question is based on a mistaken observation: the memory is actually committed when you create your array, but that's besides the point.)

Comment: @xxbbcc like I mentioned in my post, I am using the allocation as a test to see if I have memory available before I actually allocate the objects. Since the test will check if there is at least 20x the size the amount I need so that I don't allocate one at time until its at the brink and causes other object allocations in my application to fail.

Comment: @Franck I don't want to reserve all the available RAM in my application until its actually necessary since it will be rare, but possible that it will need that much.

Comment: @John just allocate the array as needed - if you're running out of memory, it'll fail. Arrays are allocated in one continuous block so be aware that you may have enough memory in several smaller blocks but not in a single massive block. Your problem still sounds like an X-Y problem, though - if you definitely know you criitcally need that much memory, you should reserve it and use your own memory manager.

Comment: @xxbbcc I want to use the available RAM for caching data files in RAM so that the performance increases since time is vital. However, I don't want to use ALL the RAM since that will cause failures throughout my application when it attempts to allocate other new objects so I want to allocate the maximum minus 1 gig or so to be safe. Right now, my application allocates as much as possible and it fails when it runs out of memory. So my answer is to test if 20x the amount I want is available, but if I allocate it with the byte array, it doesn't throw the out of memory exception like I want.

Comment: @John Ok, so then pre-allocate 1GB as you start and write a memory manager that keeps track of what's in it. (A memory manager can be as simple as a list of what's where and how long it is to something complex that handles gaps / moves things around as things get added / removed and the block gets fragmented.)

Comment: @xxbbcc that doesn't solve my issue, because if I successfully allocate 1GB, but the only available memory is 1.00001GB, it will cause my application to start failing because all the memory has been reserved for that array. So I need a method to find out how much memory is actually available at any given moment so that if it is too close to the brink, it will deallocate some of the cache and avoid caching new objects.

Comment: @John I think you misunderstand. First, decide how much memory you need (or create a setting for it) - this will either be an absolute number or a percentage. The computer either has it or it doesn't - once you allocate an array of that size, it's yours - problem solved. If, however, you want to actually follow memory trends and release memory under pressure, your question is _way_ too broad. You should just use `MemoryCache` or something similar - the logic behind memory-aware caching is pretty complex.

Comment: @xxbbcc I don't want to have a preset size since every user will have a different amount of RAM installed and RAM free (not being used by other applications). I want to use 90% of the RAM that is not currently being used. Its not a complicated problem, I just need to know how much is currently available so that I know how much to allocate and how much to deallocate when another program on the user's computer starts taking the last 10%.

Comment: Given this is a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where the Y has emerged in the comments, please move those details into the question and delete the comments @John. It will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Task Manager is not a very good memory profiler.  It shows the working set, the number of RAM pages your code has allocated.  But your code runs on a demand-paged virtual memory operating system.  Like Windows or any other in common use today.  You've allocated the virtual part but you haven't demanded anything yet.  Doesn't happen until you actually access the array elements.  You'll like to add the "Commit" or "VM Size" columns to Task Manager  (actual names depends on the OS version).

Comment: @John You have a king of [XY problem](meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but i think it's more a badly formulated question. What you want a resource monitor that specifically monitor the memory and it's allocated property. To allocate memory in order to "lock" it (not assigning to a variable) to make sure other apps cannot use it and you are stuck with nothing left at a critical point later on that would be another question so it doesn't become too broad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Made a function that will attempt to actually allocate the memory I specify (and throw an exception if its not possible rather than lie about it) and will be instantly collected by the garbage collector if it succeeds.

```
bool IsMemoryAvailable(int amount)
{
    int size = (int)Math.Sqrt(amount) / 2;

    try
    {
        using (Bitmap bmpTest = new Bitmap(size, size))
        {

        }

        GC.Collect();

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Explicitly calling gc.collect is not recommended. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2008/05/01/forcing-a-garbage-collection-is-not-a-good-idea/

Comment: @bhmahler its absolutely required, otherwise it will not release the memory that was just allocated and when other legitimate calls to allocate a new object will fail throughout the application.

Comment: That’s not true. When you use a using the object is disposed when you exit. That tells the garbage collector that it is ready for removal and it will do so when needed. Do some more research on the garbage collector in .net

Comment: @bhmahler test my original question's code yourself and let me know when you confirmed how wrong you are.

Comment: How many bytes `Bitmap` will consume with allocation by default, `size * size * 4`? Check [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e36948f559002bf98e1fae38ed13afe53d4cdcd5/src/libraries/System.Drawing.Common/src/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs#L54) and let me know when you confirmed how wrong you are. You forgot to set `PixelFormat` explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you *really* want to map all that memory, then reiterate through the array and fill it with zeroes. It's linear time anyway. Use `Array.Clear` for that.
C# really isn't made for such memory optimization in mind. The only resources you should be ever caring about are unamaged resources. The correct way of thinking about the rest of memory consumption in C# is *not thinking* about it at all. I honestly had no idea how C# handles memory allocation during an array declaration before searching for this question, and that's kinda the point, I'm not using a high-level abstract language to care about such stuff. It only makes sense if you have a working application that encounters a memory bottleneck and you need to optimize.

There *is* a [`stackalloc` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/stackalloc), which you could maybe bend to your use, but it's an unsafe operator. Also there is [`GC.GetTotalMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory(v=vs.110).aspx), which can show you the current memory usage (of managed objects), and [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo.totalphysicalmemory.aspx) which will give you the total RAM of the machine (don't mind the VB in the name, it's a .NET Framework method, just add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices`), so using this you could achieve your goal of knowing more or less if there's enough memory for you to allocate your array.

### Update:

Since C# 7.2 it is now permitted to use `stackalloc` without entering an `unsafe` context with the `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` types. I cannot, however, find whether or not a `stackalloc` instruction is required to actually allocate from the stack or if it can be omitted if the allocated buffer is unused, so it might still be necessary to actually iterate through the buffer to trick the compiler into thinking the allocation is needed.

Comment: "commit" is the wrong word, the address space *is* committed after `new` and the OS has reserved space for the allocation in the paging file.  "mapped" is the better word.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to allocate all of the bytes, you can use Array.Clear, it will fill all values with 0

```
Array.Clear(test, 0, test.Length);
```

This simple console app lets you monitor the memory usage as it's created and populated with clear

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Memory usage 7.1 MB
        Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to allocate");
        Console.ReadKey();
        byte[] data = new byte[1024*1024]; //Memory still 7.1 MB
        Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter to Fill with zeros!");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Array.Clear(data, 0, data.Length); //Memory now 8.1 MB
        Console.WriteLine("1MB filled, hit enter to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I fill all the bytes of the array I allocate, it takes over 500 milliseconds which is much to slow when I need to be less than 16 milliseconds for every function call. I tried setting the last element to a value to see if it would allocate the physical pages so the test would work, but it seems to not work. Also since the garbage collector doesn't take the byte array when I do GC.Collect(), it causes the test to fail and when I go to allocate a Bitmap later in my application, it throws a out of memory Exception.

Comment: @John No way, will it take 500ms just to fill an array. How do you fill your array and how did you measure it?

Comment: Calling clear fills the array with zeroes and allocated the memory. You can see it happen watching the ram. It really sounds like you are using the wrong tool for the job. If you need this kind of explicit memory management than you should be managing it yourself. Also, why does your program need to allocate so much memory at one time? Can’t resources be released and memory reused?

Comment: @ckuri he is allocating in the gigabyte range. 7 mb in the example is fine but 1 gb is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you migrate to .NET 6 you can take advantage of the new introduced NativeMemory method to allocate native memory using C APIs:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

unsafe
{
    byte* buffer = (byte*)NativeMemory.Alloc(200);

    NativeMemory.Free(buffer);
}
```